# Skype port: open or closed?

Tags: skype

both Ubuntu 12.04 sudo Netstat,sudo ufw status, and my firewall gfw assure me that my port at skype is open and listened to
but the free port scanners on the internet all show it not open
what gives? who is correct and why is the other wrong
is the port really not open or closed, but filtered?
if that's the case, can i still use skype?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Between your computer and internet there probably is your home router that work as firewall.
If you want your computer to be reached from the outside you need to "port forward" from your router.

This shouldn't be necessary for Skype however. The default firewall setting, in general, "all outbound allow", should be fine.